# How to get certificate from .p7b file

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, pkcs#7

Can anyone help how to extract certificate from .p7b file in C# and BouncyCastle?

Comment: Do you have any example code of at least some sort of attempt?

Comment: I tried to get the certificate from local store using the following code. But now want to read from the .p7b file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var certificateStore = new CmsSignedData(new FileStream("chain.p7b", FileMode.Open));
IX509Store x509Certs = certificateStore.GetCertificates("Collection");
ArrayList a = new ArrayList(x509Certs.GetMatches(null));
X509Certificate signerCert = (X509Certificate) a[0];

var gen = new CmsSignedDataGenerator();
gen.AddCertificates(x509Certs);
gen.AddSigner(_privateKey, signerCert, CmsSignedGenerator.DigestSha1);

CmsProcessable msg = new CmsProcessableByteArray(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(FullUnsignedMessage));

CmsSignedData signedData = gen.Generate(msg, true);
```

Comment: I figured it out. Please see the answer.

Comment: You should describe your answer, not just provide code. Besides that, it seems to me that only the first three lines matter given the question.